# Server API PostgreSQL: how to find the path to the database?

Tags: c++, c, postgresql

OK, maybe doing wrong. But want to teach PostgreSQL to distribute the files with extension functions in C++. The project works in the local network and may by about ten connections. I do not want to have FTP or other external solutions for storing images. I do not want to store images in the database. I would like so: `fs_select_file(id)`, `fs_insert_file(id, escaped_bytea)`, `fs_delete_file(id)`, e.g. `SELECT id, name, fs_select_file(id) as escaped_bytea FROM ...`. But can't find how to determine the path of the current database to use the `[PGDATA]/files`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mess with the datadir.

Even if you think it's safe to create your own contents within it, it probably isn't. Tools like `pg_basebackup` won't expect to see it.

Store your own content *outside* the PostgreSQL data directory. If you're working with a C extension that's easy enough, just let the user configure a storage location with a custom string GUC (see `DefineCustomStringVariable`).

---

Anyway, you can find the definition of the `data_directory` GUC in `src/backend/utils/misc/guc.c`. There you'll see that it's mapped to a global `char * data_directory`. A quick:

```
$ git grep data_directory src/include
src/include/utils/guc.h:extern char *data_directory;
```

shows that the extern for it is in `guc.h`. So you can access it with:

```
#include "utils/guc.h"
```

then using the `data_directory` global. But you shouldn't. Don't do this. Define your own custom GUC specifying a separate image store location.

---

While we're at it. C++.

PostgreSQL is a C application that uses `longjmp` based error handling. This goes with C++ exception handling about as well as a cigarette in an oxygen tent. C++ exceptions that cross `PG_TRY` boundaries will completely mangle the error stack. PostgreSQL error traps that cross a C++ stack subject to unwinding (any stack objects with destructors, try/catch blocks, etc) will completely mangle the C++ state.

It's possible, but hard, to combine PostgreSQL and C++. You have to isolate each piece via an interface of pure C code, and be paranoid about catching and translating error conditions at all boundaries.

If at all possible, you should instead just use C, or at least encapsulate your C++ code into a separate library that never includes PostgreSQL headers and never calls back into PostgreSQL  code. [The documentation discusses this in a little more detail](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/extend-cpp.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply and advice on the use of C++. **The problem is solved**. And it makes sense to use the user's home directory, for example: `~/pg_files_storage/[database name]`. However, the base is located on the external drive, so it is advisable to use the path of the database, it is possible relative to the storage (../[pgdata]/pg_files_storage).

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT current_setting('data_directory');`

This will show you the fully qualified path to the data directory.  I'm not clear why you need this, because mucking around in the data files is usually a good way to corrupt your database.  Anyway, I think this is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I write a library in C++, using a special API. It would be good to get the settings using function call. How to use the SQL query in the library? And, I promise :), I will not modify the database files, I need to create a subdirectory for binary files. In fact, PostgreSQL will act as a file server.